# Webkit blur with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS3, I can easily blur anything with this:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: ...
```

Right now, I am trying to create a draggable circle on top of text so that anything inside the area of that circle will be blurred:

```
position:absolute;
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
```

This technically should work, but this is what I see instead:

[image]

It looks buggy, and the most important part is that the text inside the semi-transparent circle is not blurred. Is there a way to fix it with CSS or JavaScript?

The example: http://jsfiddle.net/hSpHd/

Comment: Just looks like a buggy implementation to me. If you don't find a solution, I'd raise a WebKit bug.

Comment: Doesn't the `blur` mean that the element itself is blurred, but not what lies beneath it? If you blur a completely white object, it will still be completely white - just a bit blurred out on the edges. This does not affect what's beneath the element.

Comment: @BramVanroy - I thought that the filter is applied to the element after the text is included into the element's background?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That might only be true for its own background-image, but not for background underneath it: http://jsfiddle.net/hSpHd/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no suport for masking a filter.
That is, the filter is applied to **all** the element.
One workaround for this limitation is to have 2 elements, apply the filter to one, and mask it to transparency. Then you have the second (identical) element showing, unfiltered.

The CSS would be:

```
#one, #two {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#one {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, white 40px, lightblue 45px, transparent 50px); 
    background-position: -20px -20px;
}

#two {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);      
    -webkit-mask-position: -20px -20px;
    -webkit-mask-size: 200px 400px;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 32px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 38px); 
    background-color: white;
}
```

abd the HTML is

```
<div id="one">Lorem ipsum ...
<div id="two">Lorem ipsum ....
</div>
</div>
```

that is 2 div nested, and with the same content.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/2Qwh6/embedded/result/)

Things that I don't like about that:

You need 2 divs with the same content.

You need to synchronize the mask position (in div 2) with the background position (in div1).
You could set the circle in div 2 and maybe move everything at the same time, but then the circle is blurred.

But it's a start :-)

BTW, I have used everywhere the latest syntax of gradients. Since you are limited in compatibility from the beginning, I don't think you should care.

Answer (score 0):

this might work   `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.